# How to limit choices using enum for text color for custom controls

Tags: c#

so right now I need to make a custom control for a c# project, The main point is I would like to make one control where i can change the text-color using the control properties via a drop-down. So I would like to limit what colors can be choosen. Right now, i have Four separate color labels,, but I need one with an option to change the color from a single property. The colors are predefined using RGB values. Here is the existing label code, how can I make it into one label with multiple color options?

That is the existing label code.
http://pastebin.com/mezTBMxN
Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own custom property using a public enum containing the four colors you want. Then, when you render your control, you can set the ForeColor accordingly.

Enum:

```
public enum LabelColor
{
    Gray,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Red,
    None
}
```

Custom Property:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[DefaultValue(LabelColor.None)]
[Category("Appearance")]
public LabelColor TextColor
{
    get
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        return (ViewState["TextColor"] != null) ?
            (LabelColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(LabelColor), ViewState["TextColor"].ToString()) :
            LabelColor.None;
    }

    set
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        ViewState["TextColor"] = value;
    }
}
```

Set color in constructor or override RenderControl(). Note, you can use Color.FromArgb() if you like, however, I would recommend assigning CSS classes to keep your presentation separated.

```
switch (this.TextColor)
{
    case LabelColor.Gray:
        this.CssClass = "label-gray";
        break;
    case LabelColor.Blue:
        this.CssClass = "label-blue";
        break;
    case LabelColor.Green:
        this.CssClass = "label-green";
        break;
    case LabelColor.Red:
        this.CssClass = "label-red";
        break;
}
```

Comment: For the enum, should it be declared outside or inside the label class?

Comment: I define mine inside the control class, since it's really only used by that one control.

Comment: So, if i wanted to use those four colors for multiple controls, Would it be ok to define it on the outside? Also, can you please tell me how to use Color From Rgb instead of CSS? I haven't used CSS before.

Comment: Yes, you can define them anywhere. As for assigning the color, the enum values are your own invention, so somewhere you have to assign the 'real' color (whether CSS, or in your control class). To use FromArgb(), replace `this.CssClass = "";` with `this.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb();`

Comment: Also, any idea why it shows "The name 'EnsureChildControls' does not exist" when i compile?